# If I have the eigenvectors of (A) and (A+B) can I determine the eigenvectors of (A+UBU*) ? Where U is a unitary transformation?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have three matrices **A**, **B**, and **C**=**A**+**B**.  I know the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of **A**, **B** and **C**.

Now I need to find the eigenvectors and values of **D**= **A+UBU***, where U is a unitary transformation.

Other posts about eigenvectors of linear combinations of matrices indicate that doing this is often not possible, and but I was hoping that this might be a special case.

The goal would be to define U using 3 parameters (a direction), and express the gap between the two lowest eigenvalues of **D** as function of these paramters (it could be plotted, or at least find the minimum and maximum values).

If it helps, all the **U** matrices which I care about can be represented as a linear combination of 3 matrices, **Ux**, **Uy** and **Uz**, all of which are known. Also, **UxBUx** , **UyBUy** and **UzBUz** are known.

If need be, it can be assumed that **B** << **A** , but this is really the kind of approximation I was hoping to avoid.

Please let me know if I'm being unclear or this is answered somewhere else; I'm a chemist not a mathematician, so can easily have missed something.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, these matrices are Hermitian.

Comment: I do not have answer for your question but you may see some useful points in  matrix analysis by Bhatia

Comment: Thanks, I've actually already looked a bit at that, but couldn't find what I want. The thing is I'm not so interested in the eigenvalues, but the U which will minimize and maximize the gaps between the lowest pair, or perhaps few lowest pairs of eigenvalues. I was hoping I could perhaps use the Weyl inequalities (which Bhatia discusses extensively) to figure this out, but couldn't see how.